# Read XML file inside JAR file using Windows Batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a XML file TData.xml which has been stored at 2 different Locations.I want to see whether their versions are same or not by reading the build tags in each copy of that file. I'm able to read the copy stored in the 1st location but not the copy stored in the 2nd location as it has been stored inside an executable JAR file along with another xml file called as data.xml.

The batch code I used..

```
 @echo off
 fc D:\lucy\MasterData\TData.xml W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData.jar\TData.xml /A > nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo in SVN
    findstr "<Build>" D:\lucy\MasterData\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo  in DropBox
    findstr "<Build>" W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData.jar\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo.
    echo TData files are different.
) else (
    echo.
    echo in SVN
    findstr "<Build>" D:\lucy\MasterData\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo  in DropBox
    findstr "<Build>" W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData.jar\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo.
    echo TData files matches.

)
```

The contents of MasterData.jar are TData.xml & Data.xml

XML code for TData.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CDMDataVersion>
    <Major>3</Major>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
    <Build>19</Build>
    <Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
   </CDMDataVersion>
```

Out of the 2 xml files inside the jar file i want to read only TData.xml. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong in the above code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access directly to the `jar` content through `findstr` command, at first you must unzip the `jar` and then access the content, if you have a 7-zip installed you can do the follow:

`"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData.jar -oW:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData`

`x` is for extract. `-y` is to say yes to all prompts, and `-o` is to specify output directory note that there is no spaces between `-o` and the output: `-oW:\Master...`

The you can access your `jar` files through the folder where you extract it's content. In combination with your `findstr`:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData.jar -oW:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData
findstr "<Build>" W:\MasterDataGDDFolders\Trellis_3.3_Higher\MasterData\TData.xml
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have WinRAR installed on my machine and the path of the .exe file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR" So what changes should i make in your code??

Comment: I've never used winrar from command line, however in this link there are some samples: http://comptb.cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/. Try with `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR\unrar x c:\yourfile.jar c:\yourfile ` instead of 7z.exe.... Another possibility is that you install 7z from: http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Ya the code is working with 7Zip..only thing is that both the files are being extracted whereas I want on TData.xml file to be extracted.So what changes should i make to your code so that only a particular file is extracted and when i re-run the script again the old copy of the extracted file is deleted and replaced by the newer version of the same file??

Comment: To extract only one file you can use the follow syntax: `7z.exe x -y [archive] -o[outputdir] [fileFilter] -r` in your case `7z.exe x -y W:\...MasterData.jar -oW:\... TData.xml -r`, and before execute this to delete the file you can use windows `del` command: `del filePath`.